# Separate received from web-service as object std class

Tags: php, stdclass

I got this from web service and tried so many solution that I found in similar topics, but couldn't  separate them to use in my code:

```
stdClass Object (
    [getPropsListResult] => [
        {
            "id":16461,
            "Material":"1000001",
            "SalesDescription":"product1",
            "Plnt":"1339",
            "PlantName":"WAREHOUSE1",
            "SalesPrice":"15000"
        },
        {
            "id":16462,
            "Material":"1000001",
            "SalesDescription":" product2",
            "Plnt":"1018",
            "PlantName":"WAREHOUSE2",
            "SalesPrice":"15000"
        },
        {
            "id":16463,
            "Material":"1000002",
            "SalesDescription":" product3",
            "Plnt":"1339",
            "PlantName":"WAREHOUSE1",
            "SalesPrice":"22000"
        },
        {
            "id":32920,
            "Material":"1072941",
            "SalesDescription":"product4",
            "Plnt":"1018",
            "PlantName":" WAREHOUSE1",
            "SalesPrice":"0"
        }
    ]
)
```

Please help me how can I use these information?

Comment: What do you mean by you can not `separate` them?

Comment: I need to know for each product, its id, name and salesprice to insert in my database.

Comment: You can assign the webservice response into a variable. lets call it `$result`.
then you can do a loop on `$result->getPropsListResult` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response that you received from the web service has `json encoded` payload. To use that pay load you will require to `json_decode` it first.

Here is how you can loop over the result items to access each individual item in the list.

```
$itemList = json_decode($webServiceResponse->getPropsListResult);
foreach ($itemList as $item) {
   // access props like this
   echo $item->id;
   echo $item->Material;
   echo $item->SalesDescription;
   // and so on...
}
```

Try using the code like this:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://****.com/Pages/WebService/Keramat/KeramatWebService.asmx?wsdl');
try {
    $response = $soapclient->getCanboPropsList();
    $itemList = json_decode($response->getPropsListResult);
    foreach ($itemList as $item) {
       // access props like this
       echo $item->id;
       echo $item->Material;
       echo $item->SalesDescription;
       // and so on...
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo ($soapclient->__getLastResponse());
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo ($soapclient->__getLastRequest());
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't show anything.

Comment: What `print_r` statement creates the output that you are showing in the question?

Comment: print_r($itemList); shows nothing.

Comment: ok try running the code as shown in updated answer

Comment: I tried, but shows nothing

Comment: Based on what you have provided in your stackoverflow question if the code output is due to `print_r($response);` then it should be working, unless that code in question is not actually an output of `$response` variable.

Comment: ok let's take it a step further to troubleshoot this. what does `print_r($response-> getPropsListResult)` returns.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like:

```
$result = <webservice response>;

foreach ($result->getPropsListResult as $prop) {
   $prop['SalesPrice']; // To get salesprice
   $prop['PlantName']; // To get plant name
}
```

Comment: I tried this code, but show nothing:
   
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://****.com/Pages/WebService/Keramat/KeramatWebService.asmx?wsdl');

try {
    $response = $soapclient->getCanboPropsList();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo($soapclient->__getLastResponse());
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo($soapclient->__getLastRequest());
}
foreach ($response->getPropsListResult as $prop) {
   echo $prop['SalesPrice']; // To get salesprice
   echo "<br />";
   $prop['PlantName']; // To get plant name
   echo "<br /><br />";
}

Comment: right, so its from SOAP webservice. can you `print_r($response)` to see what you get?

Comment: When I print_r($response), I got what I mentioned in question :  stdClass Object (
    [getPropsListResult] => [
        {
            "id":16461,
            "Material":"1000001", ........